# How can I quickly search all included header files in a project for a specific symbol?

Tags: c++, c, search, header-files

Here's a problem I've had recently that just HAS to be a common pain to others here.

I'm working with someone else's legacy C code and need to find where a function or macro was defined.  The code `#include`s a bunch of different standard system libraries in addition to those from the specific project.

Is there a tool or technique to quickly find where a specific function, macro, (or other global for that matter) was defined?

I tried:

```
grep -R 'function' /usr/lib
```

and other similar *nix/bash-fu with only limited success and lots of annoying chaff to cull.  One of you sage coders out there must have a good solution to this seemingly common scenario.

I was very surprised to not find another question on this particular pain here or in my searches of the interwebs.  (I'm sure there will be angry comments if I missed one... ;-))

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: We have a combination of Opengrok and Doxygen, which helps a bit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `etags`/`ctags` from the [exuberant ctags project](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) in conjunction with an editor (emacs, vim) that understands them, or [GNU GLOBAL](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/).

Oh, and if you happen to use automake it generates a target `TAGS`.  So no need for complicated manual calls to `{c,e}tags`.

Comment: Thanks.  Although I had used ctags before, I hadn't realized I could use them for existing system libraries.  I like GNU GLOBAL's ability to also show instances of a function (i.e. reverse mapping of what CTAGS does).

Answer (score 1):

Use ctags/cscope + vim/emacs

you can google for their detail use.

if you use ctags + vim, you can :

1.go to the `/usr/include` directory, excute `ctags -f tags1 -R .` generate the tags

2.generate tags for your code in your code directory `ctags -f tags2 -R`.

3.run `:set path+=tags1,tags2` in your vim

4.under a function or marco try `CTRL+]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do, assuming you use gcc, if not just modify it accordingly.

```
gcc -E myfile.c | grep '^#' | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | sort |uniq | xargs -n 1 grep -l "MYMACROORFUNCTIONNAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse CDT. For example here is described how to setup CDT project to navigate Linux kernel source - [HowTo use the CDT to navigate Linux kernel source](http://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source).

Answer (score 0):

**vim + ctags** is the way to go. You can jump to and definition of functions, global variables, macros, etc. etc.

FYI, [browsing programs with tags](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags)

Also, if you want to **quickly switch between .c and .h files**, please refer to [this blog](http://jhshi.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/quick-switch-between-source-and-header-files-in-vim/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html) or `emacs/vim + xcscope.el` to do that easily. *I think* it's batter than ctage and etage.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the correct headers are included that directly or indirectly define what you look for, most IDEs have a jump-to-definition-functionality that works.

The tags-approaches are of course nice because they don't depend on correctly included headers.